# Tcp Socket Connection Not Work on Wirless VPN

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, vpn

I have a client server application, and I run this application on local network and everything work well. But when I use Wireless VPN network between Client and server, I can't make the connection.

The Server Code is :

```
Dim localEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, CInt(txtPort.Text))
listener = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
listener.Bind(localEndPoint)
listener.Listen(20)
```

Everything work well on local network, but on Public network using Wireless VPN, I can't make the connection
Is there anything should I add to Code, or to Firewall, ....?

Comment: This site for for programming questions. It is not clear that your question is about programming.

Comment: The Server Code is :
Dim localEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, CInt(txtPort.Text))
listener = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
listener.Bind(localEndPoint)
listener.Listen(20)
Everything work well on local network, but on Public network using Wireless VPN, I can't make the connection